# JSON to Markdown table formatting

Tags: python, json, markdown

I'm trying to build out a function to convert JSON data into a list to then be used as base for building out markdown tables.

I have a first prototype:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

data = {
  "statistics": {
    "map": [
      {
        "map_name": "Location1",
        "nan": "loc1",
        "dont": "ignore this",
        "packets": "878607764338"
      },
      {
        "map_name": "Location2",
        "nan": "loc2",
        "dont": "ignore this",
        "packets": "67989088698"
      },
    ],
    "map-reset-time": "Thu Jan  6 05:59:47 2022\n"
  }
}
headers = ['Name', 'NaN', 'Packages']

def jsonToList(data):
    """adds the desired json fields"""
    # Wil be re-written to be more acceptant to different data fields. 
    json_obj = data

    ips = []
    for piece in json_obj['statistics']['map']:
        this_ip = [piece['map_name'], piece['nan'], piece['packets']]
        ips.append(this_ip)

    return ips 

def markdownTable(data, headers):
  # Find maximal length of all elements in list
    n = max(len(x) for l in data for x in l)
    # Print the rows
    headerLength = len(headers)
  
    # expected "|        Name|         NaN|    Packages|"
    for i in range(len(headers)):
      # Takes the max number of characters and subtracts the length of the header word
      hn = n - len(headers[i])
      # Prints | [space based on row above][header word]
      print("|" + " " * hn + f"{headers[i]}", end='')
      # If last run is meet add ending pipe
      if i == headerLength-1:
        print("|") # End pipe for headers

        # expected |--------|--------|--------|
        print("|", end='') # Start pipe for sep row
        for i in   range(len(headers)):
          print ("-" *n + "|", end='')

        # seams to be adding an extra line however if its not there,
        # Location1 
        print("\n", end='') 
        
    dataLength = len(data)
    for row in data:
      for x in row:
        hn = n - len(x)
        print(f"|" + " " * hn + x, end='')
      print("|")
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    da = jsonToList(data)
    markdownTable(da, headers)
```

This code outputs as expected a table that can be used as markdown.

```
|        Name|         NaN|    Packages|
|------------|------------|------------|
|   Location1|        loc1|878607764338|
|   Location2|        loc2| 67989088698|
```

I was wondering if anyone have any good ideas regarding the placement of the words (centralized) currently I'm utilizing a `n = max(len(x) for l in data for x in l)` and then subtracts the length of the current string and ands it at the end of the output, this works well for left align but if would like to have them centered there's an issue.

Additionally general feedback on ways to optimize the code is much appreciated, if someone has build a similar function before this is my first attempt or ways to go directly from JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are at a liberty to use `pandas`, this is quite straight forward. The markdown feature is readily available. See example below.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data['statistics']['map']).rename(columns={'map_name':'Name', 'nan':'NaN', 'packets':'Packages'})
df.drop(['dont'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False,tablefmt='fancy_grid'))
```

This will provide an output like:

```
╒═══════════╤═══════╤══════════════╕
│ Name      │ NaN   │     Packages │
╞═══════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ Location1 │ loc1  │ 878607764338 │
├───────────┼───────┼──────────────┤
│ Location2 │ loc2  │  67989088698 │
╘═══════════╧═══════╧══════════════╛
```

You can use the `tablefmt` argument to apply different styles like `psql, pipe` etc.

Comment: Hey Kris, this looks like a very nice approach. Will check the current restrictions on the system and perhaps give it a go to see if this can handle the more advance use cases that I have. 

Really good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> general feedback on ways to optimize the code is much appreciated

I might do something like this:

```py
data = {
  "statistics": {
    "map": [
      {
        "map_name": "Location1",
        "nan": "loc1",
        "dont": "ignore this",
        "packets": "878607764338"
      },
      {
        "map_name": "Location2",
        "nan": "loc2",
        "dont": "ignore this",
        "packets": "67989088698"
      },
    ],
    "map-reset-time": "Thu Jan  6 05:59:47 2022\n"
  }
}

header_map = {
    'Name': 'map_name',
    'NaN': 'nan',
    'Packages': 'packets'
}

def markdownTable(data):
    rows = []
    length = max(len(v) for d in data['statistics']['map'] for k, v in d.items() if k in header_map.values()) + 2
    # build header
    rows.append('|'.join(s.center(length) for s in header_map.keys()))
    rows.append('|'.join('-' * length for x in range(len(header_map))))
    # build body
    for item in data['statistics']['map']:
        rows.append('|'.join(v.center(length) for k, v in item.items() if k in header_map.values()))
    # Print rows
    for row in rows:
        print(f'|{row}|')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    markdownTable(data)
```

Note that there is no need to restructure the data with your `jsonToList` function. Just iterate through the existing data structure. Also, I created a `header_map` dictionary, which maps the table headers to the keys within the source data. In the code, just call either the `header_map.keys()` or `header_map.values()` as appropriate.

As a general run, I try to avoid doing string concoctions with `+` unless absolutely necessary. Therefore, my use of `'|'.join()`. And of course, each call to `join` is passed a list comprehension for that row.

Finally, I first build up a collection of `rows`, then iterated over them and printed each row (adding the opening and closing pipes). I could have printed the first tine round, but including the entire joined list comprehension within an f-string is not very readable. For example:

```
print(f"|{'|'.join(s.center(length) for s in header_map.keys())}|")
```

Also, with the second loop, I only need to define the format for the opening an closing pipes once which is more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Looking back, I could have also done the `join` in the second iteration for the same reason. This would have had the additional benefit of having the rows hold the raw data, which could have additional processing done to it if needed.

The output is as follows:

```
|     Name     |     NaN      |   Packages   |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  Location1   |     loc1     | 878607764338 |
|  Location2   |     loc2     | 67989088698  |
```

Notice that with `center` justification, an odd number of characters results in favoring the right by one character. Therefore, the `Name` column and the last value in the `Packages` column appear to be off center by half a character. Probably, the number should be right-justified, which would complicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to justify text within Python there are some built-in methods to do so.

#### ljust, center, and rjust

The [ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust), [center](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center), and [rjust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) methods can be called on a `str` instance and return a string which is padded to the given length with the given fill character (space by default).

```py
>>> s = 'foo'
>>> s.ljust(10)
'foo       '
>>> s.center(10)
'   foo    '
>>> s.rjust(10)
'       foo'
>>> # Use a different fill character
>>> s.center(11, '*')
'****foo****'
```

#### Format String Syntax

Alternatively, you can use the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) (demonstrated using f-strings below). These are especially useful if you need to combine the padded string with other text as that can be included in the same string.

```py
>>> f'{s:<10}'
'foo       '
>>> f'{s:^10}'
'   foo    '
>>> f'{s:>10}'
'       foo'
>>> # Pass in a length
>>> length = 11
>>> f'{s:^{length}}'
'    foo    '
>>> # Specify a fill character
>>> f'{s:*^11}'
'****foo****'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Waylan's approach. But this time with adaptive spacing for each column. Also alignment is select-able between left right and center on a per column basis as well. `header_map` is a list of dict, which will be faster to figure out without reading the code as much.

```py
def markdownSimpleTable(header_map, data):
  # Calculate Padding For Each Column Based On Header and Data Length
  rowsPadding = {}
  for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map):
    padCount = max(len(str(v)) for d in data for k, v in d.items() if k == columnEntry['key_name']) + 2
    headerPadCount = len(columnEntry['header_name']) + 2
    rowsPadding[index] = headerPadCount if padCount <= headerPadCount else padCount
  # Render Markdown Header
  rows = []
  rows.append('|'.join(str(columnEntry['header_name']).center(rowsPadding[index]) for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map)))
  rows.append('|'.join('-' * rowsPadding[index] for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map)))
  # Render Tabular Data
  for item in data:
      rows.append('|'.join(str(item[columnEntry['key_name']]).center(rowsPadding[index]) for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map)))
  # Convert Tabular String Rows Into String
  tableString = ""
  for row in rows:
      tableString += f'|{row}|\n'
  return tableString

def markdownTableWithAlignmentSupport(header_map, data):
  # Alignment Utility Function
  def strAlign(padding:int, alignMode:str, strVal:str):
      if alignMode == 'center':
          return strVal.center(padding)
      elif alignMode == 'right':
          return strVal.rjust(padding-1)+' '
      elif alignMode == 'left':
          return ' '+strVal.ljust(padding-1)
      else: # default left
          return ' '+strVal.ljust(padding-1)
  def dashAlign(padding:int, alignMode:str):
      if alignMode == 'center':
          return ':'+'-' * (padding-2)+':'
      elif alignMode == 'right':
          return '-' * (padding-1)+':'
      elif alignMode == 'left':
          return ':'+'-' * (padding-1)
      else: # default left
          return '-' * (padding)
  # Calculate Padding For Each Column Based On Header and Data Length
  rowsPadding = {}
  for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map):
    padCount = max(len(str(v)) for d in data for k, v in d.items() if k == columnEntry['key_name']) + 2
    headerPadCount = len(columnEntry['header_name']) + 2
    rowsPadding[index] = headerPadCount if padCount <= headerPadCount else padCount
  # Render Markdown Header
  rows = []
  rows.append('|'.join(strAlign(rowsPadding[index], columnEntry.get('align'), str(columnEntry['header_name'])) for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map)))
  rows.append('|'.join(dashAlign(rowsPadding[index], columnEntry.get('align')) for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map)))
  # Render Tabular Data
  for item in data:
      rows.append('|'.join(strAlign(rowsPadding[index], columnEntry.get('align'), str(item[columnEntry['key_name']])) for index, columnEntry in enumerate(header_map)))
  # Convert Tabular String Rows Into String
  tableString = ""
  for row in rows:
      tableString += f'|{row}|\n'
  return tableString

dataInput = {
  "statistics": {
    "map": [
      {
        "map_name": "Location1",
        "nan": "loc1",
        "dont": "ignore this",
        "packets": "878607764338"
      },
      {
        "map_name": "Location2",
        "nan": "loc2",
        "dont": "ignore this",
        "packets": "67989088698"
      },
    ],
    "map-reset-time": "Thu Jan  6 05:59:47 2022\n"
  }
}

header_map = [
  {'key_name':'map_name', 'header_name':'Name'    , 'align':'right'},
  {'key_name':'nan'     , 'header_name':'NaN'     , 'align':'center'},
  {'key_name':'packets' , 'header_name':'Packages', 'align':'left'},
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("# Simple Markdown Table")
  print(markdownSimpleTable(header_map, dataInput['statistics']['map']))
  print("# Alignable Markdown Table")
  print(markdownTableWithAlignmentSupport(header_map, dataInput['statistics']['map']))
```

This is how it outputs

```
# Simple Markdown Table
|    Name   | NaN  |   Packages   |
|-----------|------|--------------|
| Location1 | loc1 | 878607764338 |
| Location2 | loc2 | 67989088698  |

# Alignable Markdown Table
|      Name | NaN  | Packages     |
|----------:|:----:|:-------------|
| Location1 | loc1 | 878607764338 |
| Location2 | loc2 | 67989088698  |
```